# What is the latest method to get all nodes and its relationship path using patterns in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I'm executing the below query in neo4j which returns me all the nodes along with its relationship paths

**Query**

```
MATCH (p:MyNode {name : "Vivek"})-[r*1..2]->(f:MyNode) return p,[x in r | type(x)] as rel,f
```

**Result**

```
{vivek} ["knows"] {Rajesh}
{vivek} ["knows","friendof] {Ezhil}
```

While this query executes right and gives me expected results i get the below warning in the neo4j browser

> Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is
>   deprecated. (Binding a variable length relationship pattern to a
>   variable ('r') is deprecated and will be unsupported in a future
>   version. The recommended way is to bind the whole path to a variable,
>   then extract the relationships: MATCH p = (...)-[...]-(...) WITH *,
>   relationships(p) AS r)

Just to upgrade my query i've tried variety of ways but nothing helped. Looking for help on this aspect.

Here is a matching combination i've tried as suggested in the help

```
MATCH p1 = (p:MyNode {name : "Vivek"})-[r*1..2]-(f:MyNode) WITH *, relationships(p1) AS r return p1
```

**Result**

> Multiple result columns with the same name are not supported (line 1,
>   column 60 (offset: 59)) "MATCH p1 = (p:MyNode {name :
>   "Vivek"})-[r*1..2]-(f:MyNode) WITH *, relationships(p1) AS r return
>   p1"

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH p1 = (p:MyNode {name : "Vivek"})-[r*1..2]-(f:MyNode) 
WITH *, relationships(p1) AS r return p1
```

when you did * in the second line, you are taking all the columns generated in first list and they are p1,p,r,f . That is why you cannot alias relationships(p1) as r again. 
To get the results as in query-1. you can do like this-

```
MATCH path=(p:MyNode {name : "Vivek"})-[r*1..2]->(f:MyNode) 
return p,[x in relationships(path) | type(x)] as rel,f
```

Comment: Hi @TheTeacher, I get the same warning executing your query but this time the warning is in the second line.

Comment: Could you please share it by updating the question